# inherit from Excel built-in dialog?

Tags: c#, windows, excel, built-in

I have an Excel UDF which takes 2 parameters, I want to utilize Excel built-in Funciton arguments window/dialog, In addition to the standard behavior(ie. you can select cell reference or type in textbox for parameter value), I want to use a dropdownlist for the second parameter, the first parameter has search ability, i.e. when you type in "C", it will pop up a list of availables values starting with "C".  I wonder if it is possible to inherit from Excel built-in dialog and how?

If not possible, I have to create custom form to make it work similar to Excel function arguments window.  I see [A window that behaves both modally and non-modally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834933/a-window-that-behaves-both-modally-and-non-modally),  maybe that's the way to go? I have not tried yet since I do not quite get what's talked there.  thanks